# How to open the standard python library in Spyder

Tags: spyder, libraries

I have a very easy question, but I can't figure it out yet. I want to open the standard python library in Spyder so I can see all the modules I can chose from. I know that in PyCharm, its very easy. You can just find it under External Libraries **>>** Lib. Thats just so easy, but how do I open the same list of modules in Spyder?

Appreciate your help :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such functionality ion Spyder, sorry.